# Kubernetes: loadbalancer and ingress

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress

In the following code, which URL will be exposed to the outside of kubernetes cluster. Is it 78.11.24.19 or 146.148.47.155?

I am trying to understand the loadbalancer and ingress here.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376
  clusterIP: 10.0.171.239
  loadBalancerIP: 78.11.24.19
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - ip: 146.148.47.155
```

Answer (score 0):

This is nicely explained on [Create an External Load Balancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer) section [Finding your IP address](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#finding-your-ip-address)
.

> You can find the IP address created for your service by getting the service information through  `kubectl`:
>
> ```
> kubectl describe services example-service
> ```
>
> which should produce output like this:
>
> ```
>    Name:                   example-service
>    Namespace:              default
>     Labels:                 <none>
>    Annotations:            <none>
>    Selector:               app=example
>    Type:                   LoadBalancer
>    IP:                     10.67.252.103
>    LoadBalancer Ingress:   192.0.2.89
>    Port:                   <unnamed> 80/TCP
>    NodePort:               <unnamed> 32445/TCP
>    Endpoints:              10.64.0.4:80,10.64.1.5:80,10.64.2.4:80
>    Session Affinity:       None
>    Events:                 <none>
> ```
>
> The IP address is listed next to  `LoadBalancer Ingress`.

Update:

It's explained at [Object Spec and Status](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/kubernetes-objects/#object-spec-and-status):

> Every Kubernetes object includes two nested object fields that govern the object’s configuration: the object spec and the object status. The spec, which you must provide, describes your desired state for the object–the characteristics that you want the object to have. **The status describes the actual state of the object, and is supplied and updated by the Kubernetes system.** At any given time, the Kubernetes Control Plane actively manages an object’s actual state to match the desired state you supplied.`

Comment: thanks. Information about the provisioned balancer is published in the Service’s .status.loadBalancer field said in  official documentation. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer

Can you please elaborate this part?

Comment: @ShafiSiyam I've updated my answer to respond to your comment.